# Import com.facebook.react

Tags: android, reactjs, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to call native functions from Android to my React native app.
I follow the [facebook tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android) and they say to add a javafile including for example :

**import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext**

I have never used Android Studio before, so my question can be very simple but what library is it and how to import it ?
I found [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/componentsdks) about facebook SDK - but they talk about **com.facebook.android** which doesn't seem to be the same.
What is more there are many component core, share, login, messenger.

My question is what SDK do I have to install to have access to com.facebook.react.bridge ? (when I google it, i have many react native package not what I want)

Comment: You're confusing React Native and the facebook SDK, which are totally different things.  But if you don't actually have a basic understanding of Java and Android I really do not recommend trying to build a bridge between the two.  You actually need to understand Java, Android, React Native, and a good amount of how all of those things work together to succeed.

Answer (score 2):

1. Firstly go File->Project Structure->Dependencies->app
2. There is (+) bottom of Declared Dependencies,click it.
3. Select Library Dependencies, and then write com.facebook.react,search and add lib in your project